# Deploy Rails project on AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

How can I deploy my Ruby on Rails project to EC2? I have a postgres database and currently use Heroku but I now need to shift to AWS.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling it may help ;o)

https://www.google.fr/search?q=deploy+rails+on+EC2

Then you have a very nice railscast that details the steps to do so with the rubber gem.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2/

Answer (score 1):

My preference is the default AWS linux then jump start it with some basic libraries:

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"
sudo yum groupinstall -y "Development Libraries"
sudo yum install -y httpd httpd-devel apr-devel libcurl-devel libxslt-devel libcurl-devel openssl-devel mysql mysql-devel ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel sqlite-devel
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails
```

git clone your rails app to your directory

bundle install --without test

Then don't forget to increase your limits (if you do any significant file io)

Add this to the /etc/security/limits.conf

```
root    soft  nofile   65535
root    hard  nofile   65535
*       soft  nofile   65535
*       hard  nofile   65535
```

Then install passenger or something like this and have it use rvm 1.9.3.